# Type error when using List<int> variable as an argument to a List<double> method parameter

Tags: dart

I'm learning the dart language, and I encountered this problem with lists.
I created a sum function to calculate the sum of a list, here is the code:

```
double sum(List<double> elements) {
   var el = 0.0;
   for (var elem in elements) {
      el += elem;
   }
   return el;
}
```

And I call it from the main menu in 2 ways:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
   var sm = sum([1, 3, 4, 6]);
   print(sm)
}
```

And it worked fine. But when I try to use a middle variable:

```
var test = [1, 3, 4, 6];
var sm = sum(test);
print(sm);
```

I get an error :

```
 Error: The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 
 'List<double>'.
 functions.dart:5
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
   var sm = sum(test);
                ^
```

I know that i have to use List as i'm using list of int but it appears that that function I made could work with both types, double and int, but i can't understand the problem when I use a middle variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example the list of `int` literals is automatically converted to `double`, which is a new feature of Dart 2.1. ([source](http://semantic-portal.net/dart-tour-built-in-types)) - int literals get converted automatically to doubles in a double context:

```
var sm = sum([1, 3, 4, 6]);
```

Before that, you would experience a compilation error and would have to explicitly provide a `double` list as a parameter:

```
var sm = sum([1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]);
```

On your second example however, you are implicitly defining a `List<int>` variable, which cannot be passed as a `List<double>` parameter.

Comment: so if I want to use variables i have to make sur its double.